# use of COUNT to count the number of times the product has been ordered

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use COUNT to well count the number of times a product has been ordered.

Below is what I have,which is not working out. I get the error

> SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

When I try to use the Group by function it said it's not a GROUP by function or that it cannot be used.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW product_summary AS
    SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS order_count, item_total AS order_total
    FROM order_item_products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear.  Add `group by`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW product_summary AS
    SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS order_count,
           SUM(item_total) AS order_total
    FROM order_item_products
    GROUP BY product_name;
```

Comment: See when i do that  oracle says "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Oh now I got it. Thank you so much. to both of you. Have a wonderful evening. :)